# C#: Casting a partial class to a parent class and putting it into a Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

Say I have the following classes:

```
public class Parent
{
   public Property1 {get;set;}
   public Property2 {get;set;}
}

public partial class Child : Parent { }

public partial class Cousin : Parent { }
```

I've got methods that return `IQueryable<Child>` and `IQueryable<Cousin>` using Property1 and Property2.

Is it possible to add both as lists into a `Dictionary<string, List<Parent>>`?

I've tried:

```
var childList = db.GetChildList() as List<Parent>;
```

But this returns null.

Would i have to return `List<Child>` and add them into a List before adding it to the dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: db.GetChildList().Cast<Parent>()

Comment: What purpose does the `partial` keyword serve here? Are there any other parts to the `Child` and `Cousin` classes in your code? This seems more like a covariance question than a partial class question.

Comment: Please. express what do you mean by Dictionary<strinf, List<Parent>>?

Comment: @BoltClock: This is EF partial class implementations, in a db first mode, so it always be generated, as well as IQueryable<Child> properties fo the external key for the object

Comment: Is that code comes form EF usage? What type of db is, What type it returns in a GetChildList()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since lists are invariant, it would need to be a right-typed list, for example:

```
var childList = db.GetChildList().Cast<Parent>().ToList();
```

Comment: +1, if GetChildList(..) is what we mean  (EF?), returns IQueryable<T>, or IEnumerable<T>

Answer (score 0):

Yes to your question. The reason is `List<Child>` is not derived from `List<Parent>`, only `Child` is derived from `Parent`.